# Не могу разобрать XML

Tags: php, xml

Получаю вот такой ответ от сайта в формате xml
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

собираю xml в массив для php и получаю такое содержимое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь получить элементы массива которые нужно

```
static function readStock()
    {
        $DOM = simplexml_load_file(self::$file_xml);
        foreach($DOM as $item)
        {
            print_r($item);
            $arFields = array();

            $EXT = trim((int)$item->sku);
            $description = trim((string)$item->description);                
            $quantity = trim((int)$item->stock_list->value);
            $UNIT_RATE = trim((int)$item->package_list->value);

            $pic = 0;
            if($PID = Product::getProductByEXT($EXT, $pic)){
                $arFields['ACTIVE'] =  'Y' ;                        

                $arFields['TOTAL_QUANTITY'] = $quantity;        
                $arFields['DESCRIPTION'] = $description;
                $arFields['UNIT_RATE'] = $UNIT_RATE;
```

при попытке вывести значения элементов в ответ приходит 00..

если делать так, как показано ниже, то php ругается

```
$UNIT_RATE = trim((int)$item->package_list[0]->value);
```

Не могу понять, что я делаю не так? в php новичок..

Comment: нужно только первое значение value которое с типом min_opt

Comment: А текст ошибки можно увидеть?

Comment: попробуйте обращаться к атрибутам $item как к массиву $item['sku'], $item['description']

Comment: Array
(
    [ext] => 0
    [description] => 
    [quantity] => 0
    [UNIT_RATE] => 0
)

Comment: вот такая лабуда выводится при попытки вытащить данные из value..